# How to import lettuce steps from other module?

Tags: python, lettuce

I'd like to share some steps between different features in lettuce. Putting them in some module then importing this module, before steps definitions, simply does not work. I get messages that steps are not defined.

Is there any straightforward way to share steps definitions between different features in lettuce?

Comment: That's strange because the way you tried should work (it worked for me ). Can you give your project's structure?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UTSM1PeP - here is tree of project catalog.

I import modules from common_steps to every functionality test - they are imported, so are the functions, but lettuce does not see them. Can't give much more detail because it is a commercial project.

Answer (score 1):

create directory structure like this:

```
root:
    __init__.py
    features:
        __init__.py
        steps.py: # global steps
        some_features:
            __init__.py
            file.feature
            steps.py # specific steps
```

define your global steps in `root/features/steps.py` and in `root/features/some_features`

do: `from root.features.steps import *`

meaning: the steps for some_features are `some_features/steps.py`

Answer (score 0):

Do steps that are defined inside app's directory work properly? I wonder if they do, because importing a function is basically the same as defining it in same file.

As described in [lettuce docs](http://lettuce.it/tutorial/simple.html#lettuce-project-structure) all your lettuce files (features and steps) must be inside app/features directory. I'd recommend you to move your steps and features files to 'features' directories inside your apps. I think that'll solve the problem.